# How to embed broker? Missing broker.xml

Tags: java, activemq-artemis

Currently I am writing a class which shall start and configure an embedded JMS server and after that mediate between Producers and Consumers.

I found this [reference](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/embedding-activemq.html)  and it says that it needs a `broker.xml` but doesn't supply any example. Can somebody tell me what I need to put into the file.

And also: Will it work to start the `BrokerServer` as I imagine?

EDIT:

Now I use this code:

```java
...

        SecurityConfiguration securityConfig = new SecurityConfiguration();
        securityConfig.addUser("guest", "guest");
        securityConfig.addRole("guest", "guest");
        securityConfig.setDefaultUser("guest");
        ActiveMQJAASSecurityManager securityManager = new ActiveMQJAASSecurityManager(InVMLoginModule.class.getName(), securityConfig);

        // Step 2. Create and start embedded broker.
        ActiveMQServer server = null;
        try {
            server = ActiveMQServers.newActiveMQServer("broker.xml", null, securityManager);
            server.start();
            System.out.println("Started Embedded Broker");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
...
```

But I receive the error:

`java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: broker.xml`

Even so the the file is right next to the class. Where does the file has to be?

`broker.xml`

```xml
<configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:activemq" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-server.xsd">
   <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core">

      <persistence-enabled>false</persistence-enabled>

      <acceptors>
         <acceptor name="in-vm">vm://0</acceptor>
      </acceptors>

      <security-settings>
         <security-setting match="#">
            <permission type="createAddress" roles="guest"/>
            <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
            <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
            <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
            <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
            <permission type="consume" roles="guest"/>
            <permission type="send" roles="guest"/>
         </security-setting>
      </security-settings>
   </core>
</configuration>
```

Comment: @JustinBertram I edited my question concerning your request. As well I changed to the latest documentation reference. Still there is no explanation about the `broker.xml` and I do not understand if this is what I am looking for as stated in my request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/embedding-activemq.html) you cited actually covers 2 different ways to embed an instance of ActiveMQ Artemis. The first way uses a `broker.xml` on your classpath. The second way just uses the configuration API (i.e. programmatic configuration without XML config).

ActiveMQ Artemis ships with *many* examples in the `examples` directory demonstrating all kinds of ways to configure the broker via `broker.xml`. There are even 2 examples demonstrating the two different ways to embed the broker as discussed in the documentation. Check out the example in `examples/features/standard/embedded-simple` for a demonstration of how to embed a broker and use a `broker.xml` on the classpath for configuration. Check out the example in `examples/features/standard/embedded` for a demonstration of how to embed a broker and configure it programmatically.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I just found those. Really good examples. Just one more question: What does 'classpath' actually mean? I copied it now tp multiple positions but I always receive the error from my edit.

Comment: Are you not familiar with Java's concept of a classpath?

Comment: My resource folder was not tagged as ressource folder in intellij! Thank you for all your help!